# Is it possible to AutoFill Contact in TextField?

Tags: swiftui, textfield, autofill

Is it possible to integrate contact autofill in SwiftUI `TextField`? Like in this NYTimes app login form:

I bet it's just a Web View so the AutoFill feature is inherited from Safari. Looking for SwiftUI solution.

[image: Email Address AutoFill form]

Answer (score 0):

Use `textContentType`:

```
TextField("Enter your email", text: $emailAddress)
    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this and doesn't suggest any email, until you start typing a contact's name.